Report on opened emails
I'm trying but failing miserably to create a searchkit report that shows contacts in a particular mailing group who haven't opened a mailing in a specific number of months.
Any help on how to build this greatly appreciated.

Can you do the opposite? e.g. if the mailing group is called "A", then make another group called B that is all contacts in the group who HAVE opened the mailing in X months. Then compute all contacts in A not in B.

The snippet below should give you list of contacts with mailing name, date delivered and date opened and diff days
[
  [
    "SavedSearch",
    "save",
    {
      "records": [
        {
          "name": "test",
          "label": "test",
          "form_values": null,
          "mapping_id": null,
          "search_custom_id": null,
          "api_entity": "Mailing",
          "api_params": {
            "version": 4,
            "select": [
              "id",
              "name",
              "Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01.contact_id.display_name",
              "Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01_MailingEventQueue_MailingEventDelivered_event_queue_id_01.time_stamp",
              "Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01_MailingEventQueue_MailingEventOpened_event_queue_id_01.time_stamp",
              "DATEDIFF(Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01_MailingEventQueue_MailingEventOpened_event_queue_id_01.time_stamp, Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01_MailingEventQueue_MailingEventDelivered_event_queue_id_01.time_stamp) AS DATEDIFF_Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01_MailingEventQueue_MailingEventOpened_event_queue_id_01_time_stamp_Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01_MailingEventQueue_MailingEventDelivered_event_queue_id_01_time_stamp"
            ],
            "orderBy": [],
            "where": [
              [
                "scheduled_date",
                "<",
                "now"
              ],
              [
                "Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01_MailingEventQueue_MailingEventDelivered_event_queue_id_01.time_stamp",
                "IS NOT EMPTY"
              ]
            ],
            "groupBy": [],
            "join": [
              [
                "MailingJob AS Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01",
                "LEFT",
                [
                  "id",
                  "=",
                  "Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01.mailing_id"
                ]
              ],
              [
                "MailingEventQueue AS Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01",
                "LEFT",
                [
                  "Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01.id",
                  "=",
                  "Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01.job_id"
                ]
              ],
              [
                "MailingEventOpened AS Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01_MailingEventQueue_MailingEventOpened_event_queue_id_01",
                "LEFT",
                [
                  "Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01.id",
                  "=",
                  "Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01_MailingEventQueue_MailingEventOpened_event_queue_id_01.event_queue_id"
                ]
              ],
              [
                "MailingEventDelivered AS Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01_MailingEventQueue_MailingEventDelivered_event_queue_id_01",
                "LEFT",
                [
                  "Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01.id",
                  "=",
                  "Mailing_MailingJob_mailing_id_01_MailingJob_MailingEventQueue_job_id_01_MailingEventQueue_MailingEventDelivered_event_queue_id_01.event_queue_id"
                ]
              ]
            ],
            "having": []
          },
          "expires_date": null,
          "description": null
        }
      ],
      "match": [
        "name"
      ]
    }
  ]
]


Thanks @Pradeep, but how do I add that query to searchkit to run? Or can you do a screenshot of the settings you used to create the search.

Go to searchkit page and click on Import and paste the above code
